# failed to upgrade to quarkus 3.6.1 due to `Could not resolve all files for configuration 'quarkusProdBaseRuntimeClasspathConfiguration'`

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy

Upgrading Quarkus version from `1.13.6.Final` to `3.6.1`

The upgrade was through these lines in gradle:

```
  dependencies {
        classpath "io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }

implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
```

With the values:

```
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPluginVersion=3.6.1
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPlatformVersion=3.6.1
```

Got such error when executing the gradle build:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tpgraph:quarkusGenerateCode'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':tpgraph:quarkusProdBaseRuntimeClasspathConfiguration'.
   > Could not resolve io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp:3.6.1.
     Required by:
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:3.6.1
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-json:3.6.1
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health:3.6.1
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus:3.6.1 > io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer:3.6.1
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb:3.6.1 > io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonb:3.6.1
      > Could not resolve io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp:3.6.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/io/quarkus/quarkus-jsonp/3.6.1/quarkus-jsonp-3.6.1.pom
            > Could not resolve io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp-parent:3.6.1.
               > Could not resolve io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp-parent:3.6.1.
                  > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/io/quarkus/quarkus-jsonp-parent/3.6.1/quarkus-jsonp-parent-3.6.1.pom
                     > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-project:3.6.1.
   > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-binding-provider:6.2.6.Final.
     Required by:
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:3.6.1
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb:3.6.1
      > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-binding-provider:6.2.6.Final.
         > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-json-binding-provider/6.2.6.Final/resteasy-json-binding-provider-6.2.6.Final.pom
            > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:providers-pom:6.2.6.Final.
               > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:providers-pom:6.2.6.Final.
                  > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/org/jboss/resteasy/providers-pom/6.2.6.Final/providers-pom-6.2.6.Final.pom
                     > Could not find dev.resteasy.tools:resteasy-parent:2.0.4.Final.
                       Searched in the following locations:
                         - file:/home/yunding/.m2/repository/dev/resteasy/tools/resteasy-parent/2.0.4.Final/resteasy-parent-2.0.4.Final.pom
                         - https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/dev/resteasy/tools/resteasy-parent/2.0.4.Final/resteasy-parent-2.0.4.Final.pom
                         - https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/dev/resteasy/tools/resteasy-parent/2.0.4.Final/resteasy-parent-2.0.4.Final.jar
   > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-p-provider:6.2.6.Final.
     Required by:
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:3.6.1
         project :tpgraph > io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb:3.6.1
      > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-p-provider:6.2.6.Final.
         > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-json-p-provider/6.2.6.Final/resteasy-json-p-provider-6.2.6.Final.pom
            > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:providers-pom:6.2.6.Final.
               > Could not resolve org.jboss.resteasy:providers-pom:6.2.6.Final.
                  > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.mycompany.ai/artifactory/mycompany-mvn-virtual/org/jboss/resteasy/providers-pom/6.2.6.Final/providers-pom-6.2.6.Final.pom
                     > Could not find dev.resteasy.tools:resteasy-parent:2.0.4.Final.
```

I did not explicitly declare any dependency of things like `io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp` in my gradle scripts, so I think that was required by Quarkus? But it seems it cannot figure out the dependency itself..

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest looking at a generated project from code.quarkus.io and comparing with what you have

Comment: If you use the quarkus cli and run `quarkus update`, that can often do the update for you. https://quarkus.io/guides/update-quarkus has more instructions on the tool.

Comment: @HollyCummins 
quarkus update would give me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the `mavenCentral()` after the `mavenLocal()`.

```
   repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryURL}/xxx-mvn-virtual"
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
```